# How can I make a jQuery UI Menu Button or find an already existing extension?

Tags: jquery-ui

I've just started working with jQuery UI, and while at first it looked like a wonderful tool, I've found that it lacks exactly what I need: a menu button widget.

What I want is the functionality of the jQuery UI Menu Widget, but with some additional bits, primarily a button/clickable area that will show/hide the menu. This alone is simple enough, but what is driving me mad is adding the expected keyboard functionality to this. When a button expands a menu, one expects that clicking outside that menu or pressing ESCAPE will close that menu, and while this works for the widget's submenus, it isn't built into the main widget.

I've been reading about the Widget Factory and extending/modifying widgets, but I'm completely lost as to how to accomplish this specific problem, and I can't seem to find any answers to this that aren't many years old. I've even tried overriding the "collapse" function in the menu instance, but the problem is that I don't quite understand the flow of the code. I basically added an 'else' statement that calls the 'click' event on the button when the conditions for closing a submenu aren't met. This just creates all sorts of weird bugs and I know I don't really have any idea what I'm doing.

A code example of how this is done would be greatly appreciated, but this is a common enough website behavior that I imagine someone has already put this together. I'm just not finding anything up to date.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sorry, there is no Widget of that nature in jQuery UI. It would be pretty easy to make. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Well, I'm trying to provide code examples and clarify, but I'm blind and this site is not very accessible. If someone could just go ahead and delete this thread: I can't provide what is necessary to get a decent answer.

Comment: I added an answer that is using Snippets. I'm not sure how easy they are to navigate when blind. I am happy to move the code to a code block that might be easier to navigate. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't address my problem. I need extra keyboard functionality on the Menu widget to make it a proper menu button, but the widget factory documentation doesn't explain how to do this. My attempts to copy and extend the widget's code have also failed, and I can't figure out how to post code snippets to show examples of what I've tried.

Comment: If you find S.O. Snippet hard to use, you can also PastePin your code and link to it from the comments. Not advised method, but it gets the info to people that can help. What I read is you want to a give Focus to the menu when it appears and allow Arrow key navigation along with selection via Enter I assume? This is a feature of the Autocomplete menu, so it can be done. Please comment with your current code and any other notes you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not find a Widget that is needed, you can combine various elements and use them together.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".widget button").button();
  $(".widget button").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($("#menu").is(":visible")) {
      $("#menu").hide();
    } else {
      $("#menu").show().menu("focus", null, $("#menu .ui-menu-item:first"));
    }
  });
  $("#menu").menu({
    select: function(e, ui) {
      console.log(ui.item.text().trim());
    }
  }).hide();
});
```

```css
.ui-menu {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="widget">
  <h1>Widget Buttons</h1>
  <button>A button element</button>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="ui-state-disabled">
      <div>Toys (n/a)</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>Books</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>Clothing</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>Electronics</div>
      <ul>
        <li class="ui-state-disabled">
          <div>Home Entertainment</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>Car Hifi</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>Utilities</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>Movies</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>Music</div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>Rock</div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div>Alternative</div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>Classic</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>Jazz</div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div>Freejazz</div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>Big Band</div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>Modern</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>Pop</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-disabled">
      <div>Specials (n/a)</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Base Examples:

- https://jqueryui.com/menu/
- https://jqueryui.com/button/

You can also make use of the [Widget Factory](https://jqueryui.com/widget/) to create your own.